# What algorithm is prefered to do a x b mod P with big numbers (256 bits)

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, mathematical-programming, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to implement multiple precision arithmetic operations modulo `P`, with `P < 2^256`.
More specifically, `P = 2^256 - 2^32 - 977`.

I want to support the following operations: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `pow` (each mod P)

As P is close to `2^256`, numbers are represented with 8 u32 or 4 u64.

`a + b mod P` can be done like this (in pseudo code):

```
n = a + b
if overflow: # i.e. over 2^256
    # add 2^256 - P to come back modulo P
    n += 2**32 + 977
else:
    if n >= P:
        # P <= n <= 2^256
        n -= P
```

--

For `a * b mod P`, my first intention was to simply do a **long multiplication** but that seems slow as I would need the carry to be 256 bits as well.

Are there any recommended algorithms to calculate `a * b modulo P` efficiently (using  arrays of u32 / u64)?

I'm mostly interested in the multiplication because:

- `a^x mod P` can be an optimized version of `a * a * ... * a mod P`
- `a / b mod P` can be calculated as `a * b^{P-2}` using [fermats little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Note: Bitcoin implements these operations with numbers represented [with 10 x uint26](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/secp256k1/src/field_10x26.h) instead of 8 uint32 so each "digit" keeps 6 bits but I'm not familiar with their methods.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Example_implementations, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Computational_complexity, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochanski_multiplication, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication

Comment: Thanks, Montgomery is actually slower as it requires 2 costly transformations, it's better suited to use it for exponentiation from what I read.

Kochanski seems like a good fit but there is little detail on the algo to be honest

Comment: If you have a specific question about how Kochanski multiplication works, that might make a good question (maybe ask it separately as a separate post).  The algorithm in the Wikipedia article seems pretty clear to me.  It sounded like you were most interested in exponentiation based on your "I'm mostly interested in..." statement.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140881/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one reasonable method:

To multiply a 32-bit integer by a 256-bit integer modulo $P$, multiply the integers using arbitrary-precision arithmetic (see [How do computers perform operations on numbers that are larger than 64 bits?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140881/755;) this can be done with 8 32x32 -> 64 multiplications, and then some 32-bit additions) to get a 288-bit product, then reduce the product modulo $P$ (divide the product by $P$, and keep the remainder).

To multiply a 256-bit integer $X$ by a 256-bit integer $Y$ modulo $P$, write

$$X = 2^{224} X_7 + \dots + 2^{32} X_1 + X_0,$$

then do the following:

- set $B := 0$
- for $i := 7,6,\dots,0$:

  - set $A := X_i \times Y \bmod P$
  - set $B := 2^{32} \times B \bmod P$
  - set $B := A + B \bmod P$

At the end, $B$ will hold the product $A \times B \bmod P$.  Each step can be computed using the method of the first paragraph of this answer as it only involves 32x256 -> 288 modular multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with your particular P, $a \cdot 2^{256} + b \mod P = $ $ b + a \cdot (2^{32}+977) \mod P$. The result will only rarely be P or slightly larger, in which case you subtract P once more.